# browser plugin to detect decible level, not just volume

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

With html5, chrome extensions, or any browser plugin, is there a way to detect the actual decible level of a audio file for the purpose of auto-leveling the volume? Adjusting the volume would preferably come from the browser via a response to JavaScript, but if the plugin could only adjust the system volume that's fine too.

Does this exist in any type of browser plugin? If not, is it possible?

Comment: You can probably do it with Adobe Flex. Read the audio file, calculate the norm of the max volume, and adjust appropriately. Your users will require Flash though.

Comment: Can't you just preprocess your audio files using a [ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain) tool? It's not perfect in that it doesn't measure sound output, but it certainly tries to analyse the perceived loudness.

Comment: I think he wants to calculate the replay gain as the track is playing.

Comment: @idbehold My point is that that's... kind of pointless. For one replaygain analysis or any other kind of sensible volume leveling requires the whole track or even an album up front. Unless you want every moment of the track to sound equally loud which sounds kind of ludicrous - I'm not an audio person but this sounds like it would mangle any track that's at all dynamic.

Comment: Thanks all, @Derek, my actionscript is a bit rusty and i'm not a huge fan, but i'll actually consider this for a fast solution since i'm the only intended user anyway. @millimoose/idbehold, i sort of planned on taking the first 5-10 seconds of buffering as my perieved loudness level and adusting accordingly, but do realize that's error prone.

Comment: as for preprocessing files server-side, that is going to be next question (since squeezing that topic here would get everything rejected as too broad or something). Meanwhile, on the client-side,  I don't see any players on your link that would work in a browser. Are you familiar with any of the listed 'scanners' to have a preference?

Comment: @EliATaylor I now realize that link provides incomplete information. For MP3 files, the [`mp3gain`](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/) program exists that, I believe, should **not** require a compatible player. Instead, it adjusts the gain of the MP3 file "in-place", IIRC by means of some standard per-frame metadata that lets you do this without actually reencoding the track. Now, I'm not 100% sure of this, but you can test this by creating two versions of the file, one with drastically reduced loudness, and playing it in the web player of your choice to see if there's a difference.

Comment: @EliATaylor [This](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=MP3Gain) corroborates what I remember: "With most other formats, the necessary loudness adjustment of ReplayGain is stored as metadata, thus leaving the encoded results alone. With MP3Gain, the loudness adjustment is done on the data itself, albeit in a lossless/reversible way." If you want MP4 support, there's also the fork [aacgain](http://aacgain.altosdesign.com/) which operates similarly (adjusting the track gain directly using the same algorithm), but they state it's just "functionally"  but not "completely" reversible.

Comment: @EliATaylor As for doing this in the browser, there's the [Web Audio API](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20au) - as you can see it's mostly unavailable. Flash can probably do this as well but then you'd have to either find an analyser or write one yourself and figure out how to correlate the file loudness to the needed player volume adjustment and on the whole it just seems that server-side is the way to go here, unless you're streaming. (Which is a valid use case, but should be stated up front since it changes the game entirely.)

Comment: @EliATaylor Oh, and one last thing: don't notify multiple people in a single comment. The one you posted only got "sent" to Derek, I wouldn't have gotten back to this question had I not left the tab open.